# Concatenate two column values in LINQ Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a table where there are two columns. First_Name and Last_name. I am populating a gridview using LINQ.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myLinQtoSQLClassDataContext objDataContext = new myLinQtoSQLClassDataContext();

        var allUserList = from CurrentUser in objDataContext.Users.Where(c => c.Is_Deleted != false)                              
                          select new
                          {
                              CurrentUser.First_Name, 
                              CurrentUser.Last_Name,
                              CurrentUser.Email_ID,
                              CurrentUser.GUID
                          };

        GridView1.DataSource = allUserList;
        GridView1.DataBind();                              
    }
```

I can retrieve the values using LINQ, but I want to concatenate the first name and last name with a space in between.

The equivalent SQL query what I am trying to achieve would be like this:

```
Select First_name + ' ' + Last Name as Username, Email_ID, GUID
From tbl_Users where Is_Deleted != false
```

How can I achieve this through the lambda expression?

Comment: In SQL you should normally use `' '` to mean a string containing a space., not `" "`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use string concatenation:

```
select new
{
    Username = CurrentUser.First_Name + " " + CurrentUser.Last_Name,
    CurrentUser.Email_ID,
    CurrentUser.GUID
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
select new
{
    FullName = CurrentUser.First_Name + " " + CurrentUser.Last_Name,
    CurrentUser.Email_ID,
    CurrentUser.GUID
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var allUserList = from CurrentUser in objDataContext.Users.Where(c => c.Is_Deleted != false)                              
                  select new
                  {
                      Name = CurrentUser.First_Name + " " + CurrentUser.Last_Name, 
                      CurrentUser.Email_ID,
                      CurrentUser.GUID
                  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You should give your [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) 'keys' (read-only properties):

```
select new
{
  Name = CurrentUser.First_Name + " " + CurrentUser.Last_Name,
};
```

And then just concatenate the string on assigning the user name.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at this [CLR Method to Canonical Function Mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx.)

.Net provides many methods that can be directly mapped to the queries ull have to use one of them to add two strings
so one that u can use is

```
select new 
{ 
    Username = Concat(first_Name,Last_Name), 
    CurrentUser.Email_ID, 
    CurrentUser.GUID 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another variation that works and has not been listed:

```
var allUserList =  objDataContext.Users.Where(c => c.Is_Deleted != false).
     Select(s => new{First_Name + " " + Last_Name, Email_ID, GUID});
```

Comment: `var allUserList =  objDataContext.Users.Where(c => c.Is_Deleted != false).Select(s => new{FullName = First_Name + " " + Last_Name, Email_ID, GUID});` worked for me. I needed to add FullName as a Field

Answer (score 0):

```
select new
{
    Username = string.Format("{0} {1}", CurrentUser.First_Name, CurrentUser.Last_Name),
    CurrentUser.Email_ID,
    CurrentUser.GUID
};
```